# iBeacon start advertising on application did enter background

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral

Upon `applicationDidEnterBackground` or `applicationWillResignActive` I need to `startAdvertising` but I get this error:

```
CoreBluetooth[API MISUSE] <CBPeripheralManager: 0x146a4e30> can only accept this command while in the powered on state.
```

I use:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    _locationManager.delegate = self;
    [_locationManager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:_runningBeacon];
    NSLog(@"stop monitoring");
    NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"23542266-18D1-4FE4-B4A1-23F8195B9D39"];
    self.beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid major:1 minor:1 identifier:@"com.devfright.myRegion"];
    self.beaconPeripheralData = [self.beaconRegion peripheralDataWithMeasuredPower:nil];
    self.peripheralManager = [[CBPeripheralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil options:nil];
    [self.peripheralManager startAdvertising:self.beaconPeripheralData];

    if ([self.peripheralManager isAdvertising]) {
        NSLog(@"peripeheralManager is advertising");
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 2):

If you want to actively *send out* BT advertisement data from your app, I think your app has to be in the foreground.
This is from the Apple Class Reference

> [..]Data advertising is done on a “best effort” basis, because space is limited and there may be multiple apps advertising simultaneously. **While your app is in the foreground**, it can use up to 28 bytes of space in the initial advertisement data for any combination of the supported advertising data keys[..]

While in background, you can only *listen* to beacons. For that you have to register your app and beacon data to the `CLLocationManager`

Comment: Can you think of a way to "bypass" this "limitation" and still be app store approved?

Comment: From what I read, Apple restricts the CoreLocation framework from advertising in the background. But it seems that it is possible to send BT advertisement data in the background with CoreBluetooth. I don't know if you can get full iBeacon functionality with this approach and I also don't know if Apple will approve this in the AppStore... but it's worth a try. Here is a GitHub project that deals with this problem https://github.com/Instrument/Vicinity/

Answer (score 1):

To silence this error, wait to call the CBPeripheralManager method startAdvertising: in the delegate method peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:.  The key here is to make sure the peripheral state is always equal to CBPeripheralManageStatePoweredOn before performing any CBPeripheralManager methods.

Comment: whilst this is a correct answer for the foreground state, the behaviour for iOS 11in the *background* is: even if the peripheral.state is .poweredOn the advertising cannot be started and the error "API MISUSE: <CBPeripheralManager: 0x00> can only accept this command while in the powered on state" is logged.